# What is the problem in this HTML5+CSS+JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, hidden

I am trying to make a feature in which, if we click on a button, a hidden div will appear, but if I try to do it, it is not working.

```js
  function reload(){
        window.reload();
    }
        function vis(x,z,a){
            var xpar = document.getElementById(x);
            var zpar = document.getElementById(z);
            var apar = document.getElementById(a);
            xpar.style.display = "block";
            zpar.style.display = "block";
            apar.style.display = "block";
        }
```

```css
   #ap{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: darkred;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            cursor: default;
        }
        #ap:active{
            color: red;
        }
        #tgt, #tgt li{
            display: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: blue;
            text-decoration: overline;
            text-decoration-color: black;
            width: 100px;
            height: 70px;
        }
        #ap button{
            background: inherit;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #ap button:active{
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="background-color: black;">

<body>
    <a id="ap" href="#" onclick="reload()"><button onclick="vis('login','sign','shop')">Click To Open!</button></a>
    <div id="tgt">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; overflow: hidden; display: inline;">
        <li id="login" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline;">Login</li>
        <li id="sign" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline;">Sign In</li>
        <li id="shop" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline;">Shop</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am editing in Brackets, if you spot any error like syntax and stuff, please write in the comments.

I am trying JS, CSS and Html with basic knowledge, so please don't think of me as a person who could understand arrays and stuff.

Edit: I have tried many solutions and I found one working, but If I apply that to my code, it still does not work.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="background-color: black;">
<head>
    <title>Hidden List</title>
    <style>
        ul li{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .liul{
            display: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-align: left;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .liul ul li{
            background: red;
            width: 60px;
        }
        #shop{
            position: absolute;
            top: 28px;
            left: 15px;
        }
        #home{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 15px;
        }
        #about{
            position: absolute;
            top: 70px;
            left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
    <div class="liul">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; overflow: hidden;">
        <li id="shop">Shop</li>
        <li id="home">Home</li>
        <li id="about">About</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    function reload(){
        window.reload();
    }
        let trg = document.querySelector("div");
        let btn = document.querySelector("button");
        trg.style.display = "none";
        btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            if(trg.style.display === "none"){
                trg.style.display = "block";}
            else{
                trg.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
});
            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 2:
I fixed the error, just some syntax errors, thanks :)

Comment: Look at your browsers' dev tools console. You have infinite recursion going on - you'll see the error something like: html:53 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. On clicking the button you may be calling the vis function, but you are inside another element with a click listener which calls reload which calls itself which calls itsefl...

Comment: Hint: You can use [HTML Validation tool](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to check for errors.

Comment: There are quite a lot of problems in your HTML. 1. You should not wrap the button with `<a>`; 2. you should not abuse using `id`; 3. avoid using inline CSS; 4. setting background color in `<html>` tag does not make sense; 5. missing `<head>` tag

Comment: Why do you customize the display for each `<li>` tag, if you can do it right away for the parent block? And wrap `window.reload()` in a `try {}` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        div{
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>ClickMe</button>
    <div>
        <h1>Ola Amigo</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
        let btn = document.querySelector('button');
        let div = document.querySelector('div');

        div.style.display = 'none';
        btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            if(div.style.display ==='none'){
                div.style.display = 'block';
            }else{
                div.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The concept is simple the hidden div appear when clicked and on double click it disappear

```html
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        div{
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>ClickMe</button>
    <div>
        <h1>Ola Amigo</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
        let btn = document.querySelector('button');
        let div = document.querySelector('div');

        div.style.display = 'none';
        btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            if(div.style.display ==='none'){
                div.style.display = 'block';
            }else{
                div.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
        function vis(x,z,a){
            
            var xpar = document.getElementById(x);
            var zpar = document.getElementById(z);
            var apar = document.getElementById(a);
            xpar.style.display = "block";
            zpar.style.display = "block";
            apar.style.display = "block";
        }
```

```css
 #ap{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: darkred;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            cursor: default;
        }
        #ap:active{
            color: red;
        }
        #tgt li{
            display: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: blue;
            text-decoration: overline;
            text-decoration-color: black;
            width: 100px;
            height: 70px;
        }
        #ap button{
            background: inherit;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #ap button:active{
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="background-color: black;">

<body>
    <a id="ap" href="#"><button onclick="vis('login','sign','shop')">Click To Open!</button></a>
    <div id="tgt">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; overflow: hidden;">
        <li id="login" style="overflow: hidden;">Login</li>
        <li id="sign" style="overflow: hidden; ">Sign In</li>
        <li id="shop" style="overflow: hidden;">Shop</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```